# Extracting specific file from a tar.bz2 containing a matching pattern

Tags: bash, tar

So I have this one **big** tarball:

```
du -sh file.tar.bz2

871M    file.tar.bz2
```

This tarball contains hundreds of files:

```
tar -jtvf file.tar.bz2 | head -3

./file-140556-001_045.txt
./file-121720-001_012.txt
./file-171008-001_036.txt
```

And I can do a `bzgrep` no problem:

```
bzgrep '0316629989093' file.tar.bz2

Binary file (standard input) matches
```

And using `bzgrep -a` I can extract the line containing the search pattern. But what I was trying to accomplish is getting the file name inside the tarball that matches the search pattern, so I can extract it without uncompressing the whole tarball.

For example:  `./file-171008-001_036.txt`

Is there any way to do this from the `bzgrep` command?

Comment: You seem to be using a tarball as a poor substitute for a properly indexed database: why?

Comment: The tarball contains hundreds of an application's log files. It's not a database.

Comment: That's my point. Assuming you want to make such lookups frequently, you should create a proper index using an appropriate tool (for example, Elastic Search perhaps) instead of working with the tarball directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried all possible options on `bzgrep` and it seems not possible to extract the filenames matching the pattern. That's too bad.

What you can do as a **workaround** is to extract files one by one and delete them after you searched into them.

Something like this :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
ARCHIVE="file.tar.bz2"
PATTERN="0316629989093"

tar -jtf "$ARCHIVE" | while read file; do
    tar -xf "$ARCHIVE" "$file"
    grep -q "$PATTERN" "$file" && echo "$file matches"
    rm "$file"
done
```

Outputs

```
file-171008-001_036.txt matches
```

- Pros: not all the file are uncompressed at once, so disk usage is limited.
- Cons: all the archive is decompressed, so the execution time is pretty bad.

Comment: I was using this exact same solution too.  :-) Thanks!